# How to ADD/EDIT/DELETE events in ICLOUD calendar using CALDAV

Tags: ios, icloud, icalendar, caldav, icloud-api

I am implementing a new functionality to manage events in ICLOUD calendar(includes my own calendar as well as other ICLOUD users calendar).I successfully implemented the functionality with CALDAV, but here I wanted to know is there any better approach to do the same.
Below mentioned steps will explain how I achieved ADD/EDIT/DELETE functionality with CALDAV in other ICLOUD users calendar.

**otheruser@gmail.com** :icloud account of a user who shares his calendar with me
**myaccount@gmail.com**: referring to my icloud account

1. otheruser@gmail.com will share his/her calendar with myaccount@gmail.com
           [image]

   Once i accept the request this calendar will be listed in myaccount@gmail.com
2. Using below CALDAV api I will get all calendars listed in my account
     [image]
3. From the response of above request I will get each calendar url and perform add/edit/delete action accordingly.

Note:Here one drawback is I need to ask each user of my application to share(but sharing it private not as public) his personal calendar with my account.

I am using c# as it is a .net application.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? or probably a reference about this?

Comment: I have implemented CalDAV API's and I feel that's is the only way to work with ICLOUD

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad so it is hard to really figure out what you are looking for.

In any case one thing about your PROPFIND request: You should also ask for the DAV:resourcetype property (defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-15.9) and, in your response, only consider the ones that have a calendar value in their resource type (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-4.2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.For your clarity, what I am trying to understand is ,Am I using the correct approach to update another person calendar?If not what will be the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes. Use of CalDAV is the recommended approach for iCloud.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way we can sync calendar with end user app specific password?

Comment: In my case, somehow every request to create a new event results `400 Bad Request`. Here is the detail of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720196/creating-new-event-to-icloud-apple-calendar-always-results-400-bad-request I'd appreciate if you have any example or reference that I can see.